# RewriteRule issue

Tags: apache

I have a rule for redirecting users to a folder:

```
RewriteRule ^f-(.*)$ download/$1
```

but this folder now contains many files on it, so how can i make a new rule to redirect to a new folder?

```
RewriteRule ^f-(.*)$ download2/$1
```

whilst the old one should still work with the same rule.

regards,
Al3in

Comment: Can you specify how this should work? Do you mean if nothing is found under the first redirect, then use the second?

Comment: @Al3in How are they supposed to work *at the same time*?

Comment: because i dont want to change th ( ^f- ) from the urls and in the same time i can't push many programs in one folder

Comment: @Al3in I ask again. **How do you expect two contradictory rules to work at the same time?** by what criterion would the server know when to use one rule, and when the other?

Comment: as i told you i want to this rules ( ^f- ) to work with any directory like download , download1 , download2 ......ect

Comment: @Al3in but **how?** How would you redirect to two folders *at the same time?* Don't you want  to redirect it to the folder the requested file actually is in?

Comment: let me explain more ....... the working folder now is ( download1 ) and now it have many programs so i want to change the folder to ( download2 ) but i want to old folder ( download1 ) work also because there are a programs on it and they have their own URLS

Comment: @Al3in ah, that makes more sense. Can you add some more details to your question with what URLs you need working.

Comment: f-DD2.jpg -- this image in download1 ... now i want to make a new url ( f-DD3.jpg ) but the image will be placed on folder ( download2 )

Answer (score 0):

you have [L] in  first rule? if you have you must remove it. (if i understand your problem correctly!)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `RewriteCond` and the "-f" test to see which download?/ directory the file really exists in.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#multipledirs